# gcloud - Can't configure my VPC connector to work with my Redis instance

Tags: google-app-engine, redis, gcloud, vpc

I'm facing a problem with gcloud and their support can't seem to help me.

So, to put my app in prod I need to use a redis instance to host some data. I'm using memorystore because I like to have everything on gcloud.

My app is in the **standard environment on app engine** so on their doc (https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-standard) they ask me to configure a **VPC connector**. But I think that the CIDR that I put is always wrong, can someone help me finding the good CIDR.

```
connectMode: DIRECT_PEERING
createTime: '2020-03-13T17:20:51.590448560Z'
currentLocationId: europe-west1-d
displayName: APP-EPG
host: 10.240.224.179
locationId: europe-west1-d
memorySizeGb: 1
name: projects/*************/locations/europe-west1/instances/app-epg
persistenceIamIdentity: *************
port: 6379
redisVersion: REDIS_4_0
reservedIpRange: 10.240.224.176/29
state: READY
tier: BASIC
```

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

**First in order to VPC connector work yor App Engine instances have to be in the same VPC & region that your Redis instance is**. If not there will not be connectivity between the two.

Also make sure you redis and app use one of the [approved locations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations). By now it's a lot of them.

Your redis instance is in europe-west1 region so to create your VPC connector you have to set the name of the VPC network your redis instance is in

(for example "default"). 
IP range you were asking about is any range (not reserved by the network redis instance is in).

So - for example if your "default" network is 10.13.0.0/28 then you have to specify something else like 10.140.0.0/28 etc. It has to be /29 - otherwise you won't be able to create the connector.

> *Why 10.13.0.0 or any other addresses ? They are going to be assigned as the source network for you apps to connect to the Redis (or any
>   other VM's) in the specified network.*

I've tested it using the command:

```
cloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create conn2 --network default /
--range 10.13.0.0/28 --region=europe-west1
```

Or you can do it using console in [Serverless VPC Access](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/connectors/list) and clicking "Add new connector";

You can also read [documentation on how to create a connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#creating_a_connector).